# Angular JS custom validation $asyncvalidator is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-validation

Trying to add an asyncvalidator to my custom username validator. However it outputs the error:

TypeError: Cannot set property 'username' of undefined.

How to I make asyncvalidator defined? I thought i would have been automatically by the NgModel controller?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
angular.module('myApp.commonDirectives', ['myApp.services']).directive('username', ['UsernameService',function(UsernameService){
 
 return {
  
     restrict: 'A',
     require: "ngModel",
     scope: {
         hasFocus: "=username"
         
     },
     link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
     
         scope.$watch('hasFocus', function(hasFocus) {
             if(angular.isDefined(hasFocus)) {

                 // on blur
                 if(!hasFocus) {
                     
                   
                     ctrl.$validated=false;
                     ctrl.$asyncValidators.username = function(value){
                     UsernameService.validate(value)
                         .then(function(resolvedData) {
                             if(resolvedData) {
                           
                              ctrl.$validated=true;
                                 ctrl.$setValidity('checking', true);
//                                 ctrl.$setValidity('username', true);
                             }
                             else {
                           
                              ctrl.$validated=true;
                                 ctrl.$setValidity('checking', false);
//                                 ctrl.$setValidity('username', false);
                             }
                         }
                      );
                 }
                 }
                 
                 // on focus
                 else {
                     ctrl.$setValidity('username', true);
                     ctrl.$setValidity('checking', true);
                 }
             }
             
         });
     }

 }
}])
```

Comment: `asyncValidators` is a new feature from angular 1.3

Comment: ^ Incredibly helpful comment....

Answer (score 2):

`$asyncValidators` is available from angularjs 1.3 and above:

https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.27/docs/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

Answer (score -1):

```
try  something like this :

angular.module('myModule').directive('usernameValidator', function($http, $q) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$asyncValidators.username = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
                return $http.post('/username-check', {username: viewValue}).then(
                    function(response) {
                        if (!response.data.validUsername) {
                            return $q.reject(response.data.errorMessage);
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                );
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: All u've done there is copied the example on the ANgular js documentation. I'd like to keep using the Restangular plugin if i can which is abstracted into the UsernameService.

Why does my code not work, whislt the above does?

Thanks for any help you can provide